# Back button in Toolbar without ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I'm using a [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) inside a Fragment (which covers the whole screen) and I want to show the back button, but I can't use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` because I'm not using ActionBarActivity.

I need something which works with API 9, so I can't use Toolbar's `setNavigationIcon`.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use `setNavigationIcon()`? The [AppCompat Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) works down to API 7.

Comment: Yes, you're right, `setNavigationIcon()` works, but when I use `android:navigationIcon` in xml it gives me this note: `Attribute navigationIcon is only used in API level 21 and higher (current min is 9)`.

Comment: like all AppCompat attributes that backport functionality, you use `app:navigationIcon` rather than `android:navigationIcon` and then they work.

Comment: Thank you, that explains it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call [setNavigationIcon(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationIcon(int)), on the `Toolbar` instance. From the documentation:

> Set the icon to use for the toolbar's navigation button.
>
> The navigation button appears at the start of the toolbar if present.
>   Setting an icon will make the navigation button visible.

if you need a ClickListener for it, you can use  [setNavigationOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener))

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use the following code:

```
public void showBackButton(final Runnable runnable) {
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            runnable.run();
        }
    });
}
```